# Should we adopt the Hebrew calendar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

Since this has not been suggested before, I'd like to know the position of the community on the little badges that indicate when a post was submitted or edited (e.g. "edited Aug 1 '12 at 23:39").
Shouldn't they be displayed in the Hebrew format (e.g. "edited 14 Tammuz 5771 at 23:39"), or an option be provided to the user?

Comment: That would be pretty confusing to many of our users.

Comment: What if they were displayed in both?

Comment: @YEZ actually I thought about it when I saw the upcoming events section where they are both displayed for the date of the next Shabbat

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA -- it's a good idea in theory, but would confuse to many people to be worthwhile

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge, why was this downvoted?

Comment: @Yarden questions on Meta that make suggestions are frequently downvoted by those who disagree with the suggestions: that's one meaning of downvoting on [Meta](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Yarden -- don't worry, you don't lose points for these downvotes; it just means that people don't agree with this suggestion

Comment: @Shokhet Thank you, I was not familiar with the rules of Meta

Comment: @Yarden Don't worry about it -- I wasn't either until recently...if it makes you feel better, your question _did_ get one upvote....[_if you have 1,000+ rep, you can see vote counts_ ;)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion (and others', as shown in the comments on the question), the Jewish date would be unclear to many site visitors. Arguably, one way around that is to display both the Gregorian-calendar and the Jewish dates. But I think the technical difficulties are insurmountable, or nearly:

- Date issues: The Jewish date changes at sunset, which time varies from day to day. The script that decides what date to show would need to take that into account. And then whose sunset should it use?
- Time issues: The Gregorian-calendar date — or, more precisely, the UTC date — has a well-defined time: [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time). The site currently shows "4:12" for 4:12 UTC. The Jewish date also has a well-defined time: Jerusalem [solar time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time), used when announcing what time the *molad* will be each month. Unfortunately, that doesn't match *anyone's* clock nowadays, and seeing 4:12 and having to subtract n:23 from it to realize when a post was actually posted is, well, a pain. And a combination of Jewish date and UTC time doesn't make much sense (no one speaks of "4:12 on 5 *Tamuz*" and means 4:12 Greenwich time except people in the Greenwich time zone) and is ambiguous (when one sunset is later than the preceding sunset, there may be two 18:17s between the two sunsets).

And even if the above issues are surmountable, I think the effort to be put into surmounting them is not worth any benefit from having the Jewish timestamp on the site. Everything online (almost) uses the UTC or Gregorian calendar, and people are well used to it.

Comment: Actually, Jerusalem solar time is ambiguous for the one-sunset-later-than-the-preceding-sunset reason also.

Comment: Plus, the bar for site-specific code is (rightly IMO) pretty high; SE has something like 120 sites, and special-casing code introduces complexity.  Even if this weren't confusing (and I would find it so, too), it probably isn't important enough -- unlike, say, handling Hebrew text well, which is essential for us though 118 of hose other sites don't care.